# Embed Excel Chart with Drop-down control into powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I have an interactive Excel chart which runs on the basis of users selecting ranges using drop down menus via the form control and I want to move this into Powerpoint 2010 for presentation purposes. However when i copy/paste the chart and workbook over it does not take the controls over with it, rather it inserts them as a picture.

Any advice on how i would get round this to enable the drop down functionality to work within powerpoint?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Interactive charts in Excel are probably best done with Power View. You can export Power View sheets to PowerPoint or SharePoint.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/power-view-explore-visualize-and-present-your-data-HA102835634.aspx